Cropper.js not displaying crop box after adding image with Dropzone.js
jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jx6pdz4y/
The problem:
I’m having trouble getting Cropper.js to display the crop box on an image after adding it with Dropzone.js. The image uploads successfully, but the crop box doesn’t appear. Cropper is supposed to work in two use cases in one modal: the first is to crop an existing images and the second is the one I am having trouble with, after a user adds an image with Dropzone. Once an image is saved, it is sent to the server.. This problem really concerns proper Cropper initialization. Here is my code:
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var cropper;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

  $('#cropperModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    console.log('shown.bs.modal called');
    let imageElm = document.getElementById('modalImage');
    $(imageElm).show();
    initializeCropper(imageElm);
    console.log('shown.bs.modal cropper');
    console.log(cropper);
  }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    if (cropper) {
      cropper.destroy();
      cropper = null;
      resetDropzone("#hidden-dropzone");
      $('#modalImage').attr('src', '').hide();
      $('#upload-button').hide();
    }
  });

  $('#upload-header, #upload-horizontal, #upload-logo').on('click', function() {
    let section = $(this).data('section');
    let imageUrl = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    openModalAndInitializeDropzone(section, imageUrl);
  });

  $('#save-changes-button').on('click', function() {
    saveCroppedImage(cropper);
  });

  function openModalAndInitializeDropzone(section, imageUrl) {
    $('#status-gyph-image').html('').removeClass('text-success').removeClass('text-danger');
    $('#cropperModal').modal('show');
    $('#modalImage').attr('src', imageUrl).data('section', section).show();
    initializeDropzone("#hidden-dropzone");
  }

  function initializeDropzone(dropzoneId) {
    console.log('initializeDropzone called, ' + dropzoneId);
    if (Dropzone.instances.length > 0) {
      Dropzone.instances.forEach(instance => instance.destroy());
    }
    let dropzoneElement = document.querySelector(dropzoneId);
    if (!dropzoneElement.dropzone) {
      let dropzone = new Dropzone(dropzoneId, {
        url: "/file/post",
        maxFilesize: 2,
        acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png",
        maxFiles: 1,
        init: function() {
          this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
            console.log('initializeDropzone addedfile');
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event) {
              $('#modalImage').attr('src', event.target.result).show();
              $('#modalImage').on('load', function() {
                console.log('......modalImage on load........');

                let imageElm = document.getElementById('modalImage');
                initializeCropper(imageElm);
                console.log(cropper);
              });
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          });
          this.on("thumbnail", function(file) {
            file.previewElement.remove();
          });
        }
      });
      $(dropzoneId).css({
        display: 'block',
        width: '100%',
        height: '200px',
        border: '2px dashed #007bff',
        padding: '20px',
        textAlign: 'center',
        lineHeight: '160px',
        fontSize: '16px',
        color: '#007bff'
      }).text('Drag and drop an image here or click to upload');
    } else {
      console.log('Dropzone already initialized for this element.');
    }
  }

  function resetDropzone(dropzoneId) {
    let dropzoneElement = Dropzone.forElement(dropzoneId);
    if (dropzoneElement) {
      dropzoneElement.removeAllFiles(true);
    }
  }

  function initializeCropper(imageId) {
    console.log('initializeCropper called');
    var $image = $(imageId);
    console.log($image);
    console.log($image.length);
    if ($image.length) {
      if (cropper) {
        cropper.destroy();
      }
      $image.cropper({
        autoCropArea: 0.5,
        responsive: true,
        viewMode: 2,
        scalable: false,
        zoomable: false,
        crop: function(e) {},
        ready: function() {
          console.log('ready called');
          cropper = $image.data('cropper');
          console.log(cropper);
        }
      });
      $('#upload-button').show();
      return $image.data('cropper');
    }
    console.error('Image element not found:', imageId);
    return null;
  }

  function saveCroppedImage(cropper) {
    if (cropper) {
      var canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas();
      let imageElm = document.getElementById('modalImage');
      let section = $(imageElm).data('section');
      if (canvas) {
        canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
          var formData = new FormData();
          console.log(formData);
          formData.append('croppedImage', blob, 'croppedImage.' + blob.type.split('/')[1]);
          formData.append('section', section);
          $.ajax('/main/uploadFile', {
            method: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(response) {
              $('#status-gyph-image').html('<strong>Successfully saved image.</strong>').addClass('text-success').removeClass('text-danger');
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              $('#status-gyph-image').html('An internal error occurred.').addClass('text-danger').removeClass('text-success');
            }
          });
        });
      } else {
        $('#status-gyph-image').html('An internal error occurred.').addClass('text-danger').removeClass('text-success');
      }
    }
  }
});

Problem:
After uploading an image with Dropzone.js, the image is displayed in the modal, but the Cropper.js crop box does not appear. The cropper variable is null when I log it after calling initializeCropper.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
What I’ve tried:
Ensuring the image element is fully loaded before initializing Cropper.
Checking the timing of when initializeCropper is called.
Adding console logs to trace the initialization process.
Expected behavior:
The crop box should appear on the image after it is added via Dropzone and displayed in the modal.
Actual behavior:
The image is displayed, but the crop box does not appear...

Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue, so that we can actually test this. (Not talking about any server-side parts of course, but your code accesses multiple HTML elements, all of which weren't provided.)

Will do, will place on jsfiddle, thanks.

Placed it on jsFiddle and linked to it in my recent edit.

Getting JS errors in the console, right after I clicked an existing image to show the modal, but before I even dropped an image. Uncaught TypeError: $image.cropper is not a function

I solved my problem. I was able to get Cropper properly initialized after adding an image using Dropzone, by ensuring that Cropper does not reinitialize.
